# Not able to start jenkins localhost:8080

Tags: java, ios, xcode, jenkins

I was able to start jenkins local server by firing below command

> java -jar jenkins.war

Initially it worked and I could start the `http://localhost:8080/`

but suddenly it started giving following error

> INFO: Completed initialization
>   Jun 07, 2018 6:28:06 PM hudson.UDPBroadcastThread run
>   INFO: Cannot listen to UDP port 33,848, skipping: java.net.SocketException: Can't assign requested address
>
> Jun 07, 2018 6:28:06 PM hudson.WebAppMain$3 run
>   INFO: **Jenkins is fully up and running**
>
> Jun 07, 2018 6:29:00 PM **org.jenkinsci.remoting.util.AnonymousClassWarnings warn
>   WARNING: Attempt to (de-)serialize anonymous class com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope$2 in file:/Users/prashantnikam/.jenkins/plugins/credentials/WEB-INF/lib/credentials.jar; see: https://jenkins.io/redirect/serialization-of-anonymous-classes/**
>
> Jun 07, 2018 6:29:18 PM hudson.model.Run execute
>   INFO: MySampleProject #262 main build action completed: FAILURE

Now page is just showing loading...loading and in the end page loading fails.

Can anyone please help on this ?

Comment: looks like the problem is not with Jenkins, but in your MySampleProject

Comment: voila...I removed MySampleProject and its started working :) thanks @Stultuske.. If you could post the answer I will accept it.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you get, shows that the problem is not in your Jenkins, but that the build of your MySampleProject fails.

So you'll have to either fix the build (fix the problem in the project) or delete the project.